# How do we configure Quartz into an lift application?

Tags: scala, configuration, installation, quartz-scheduler, lift

I use maven to create my lift project.

What's the recommended way to configure Quartz in the lift project? I have googled around but there is no comprehensive tutorial to set it up.

In ordinary spring projects, people configure Quartz with `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean`. Is there a similar way to do it in lift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is use an existing library which wraps Quartz in a nice Scala like DSL.

For example, a nice way to do this is to use the git://github.com/theatrus/akka-quartz.git the akka-quartz library to have a quartz actor which you just send jobs to.

In your boot.scala you can then create the actor and when you need to schedule a job just send it.